# Implementing a custom theme on Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, theming

I am trying to implement my own custom theme for sphinx locally. I keep running into this error:
`no theme named 'custom_theme' found (missing theme.conf?)`.
I have a `theme.conf` in my `custom_theme/` directory. Which looks like:

```
[theme]
inherit = basic
stylesheet = styles/site.min.css
```

In my conf.py I have these following relevant settings:

```
html_theme = 'custom_theme'
html_theme_path = ["."]
```

For reference I have been trying to kind of mirror the setup on this theme's repo https://github.com/snide/sphinx_rtd_theme. Using grunt to build my styles and such. But still getting that error. I was hoping someone had found some detailed docs as to how to create your own sphinx themes and templates. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up just overriding everything and putting my theme in `source/`

Comment: This answer is not really helpful. What "source" folder are you talking about? What was the process to solve the issue? What was it caused by? I have the same issue as you, but this answer does not help with solving the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to drop the theme in /usr/share/sphinx/themes.